# awarded by Some Prize or awarded Some Prize

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm a bit confused if I should use "by" or not in following sentence:

He should have been awarded (by) *Best Actor* award.

Should I use *by* or not necessary?

Comment: Not 'by'. Also it is clumsy to have 'awarded' and 'award' like that. He was awarded Best Actor, or he was given the Best Actor award.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks. Also thanks for additional suggestions.

Comment: A prize is awarded _by_ the judges _to_ the winner.